# Fechando aplicação no android 6.0

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, app-hibrido

Galera como faço para o botão sair num aplicativo com phonegap. Já tentamos todas as formas disponíveis e em nenhuma o comando executa o "sair".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297525/exit-from-app-when-click-button-in-android-phonegap  veja se ajuda

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque pelo menos sua ultima tentativa.

Answer (score 0):

Usei sempre assim e resulta sempre:

```
<a href="#" onClick="fechaMe();" data-role="button">Fechar App</a>
```

Javascript

```
function fechaMe() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: 0
votar contra
accept
Já tentei e olha a mensagem que aparece...

util.js:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitApp' of undefined at closeAplicativo (util.js:163) at HTMLDivElement.onclick (viagem.html:357)

Comment: @Mkreusch incluiu o cordova no header do documento?